# How can I get my css to match this setup? I have problems with border and element alignment

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have my site set up like this:

[image: Desired site setup]

I have problems with the borders and simply having the text to the right of the image as shown in the image.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-left: 400px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-left: 350px;
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: 350px;
}

.sectionOne {
  float: left;
}

.sectionTwo {
  float: right;
}

.jb {
  width: 45%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ach {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Joshua Eachus</h1>
<div class="jb">
  <div class="sectionOne">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/VLV0qfv/Wood-Floor-Texture-Seamless.jpg" alt="Joshua EAchus">
  </div>
  <div class="sectionTwo">
    <h2>Job Experience</h2>

    <h3>Menchies</h3>
    <p class="menchies"> Between January 2020-November 2020 I was a team member at menchies, I would mainly greet customers, help them around the store if needed and cash them out with the cash register when ready. I also am constantly busy making sure every topping and yogurt
      machine is filled up for the customers. I would usually be closing so I work 5 to 8 hour shifts every time. When closing I would put all the toppings away, clean the whole store completely and prep food for the next day.</p>

    <h3>Walgreens</h3>
    <p class="Walgreens"> I am currently working at Walgreens, which has been a great introduction into retail and has truly taught me many things. There is a diverse and large amount of tasks I do at Walgreens, one of the main tasks is running the photo department, where
      I print many kinds of photos, create canvases and many more projects. Other tasks includes stocking, outdating, cleaning duties and counting registers.</p>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="ach">
  <h3>Achievements</h3>
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/VLV0qfv/Wood-Floor-Texture-Seamless.jpg" alt="PTK">
  <p>I am a member of Phi Theta Kappa. Founded on November 19, 1918 Phi Theta Kappa is the world’s largest organization specifically devoted to recognizing the achievements of honor students at 2-year institutions. Currently, PTK has approximately 3 million
    members globally.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add this code to a snippet directly here in SO (Using the <> button)?. Will make it easier for others to see what you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve that layout would be to use CSS grid. I am using a grid layout and then nested divs for each section.

```css
.title {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 2rem 0;
        }

        .grid-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
            grid-gap: 2rem;
            padding: 0 2rem;
        }

        img {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
            display: block;
        }

        .jb,
        .ach {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
            grid-gap: 1rem;
        }
        
        .ach * {
            grid-column: 1 / -1;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .ach .sectionOne img {
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .grid-container, .jb, .ach {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  
  .sectionOne {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Joshua Eachus</h1>
<div class="grid-container">
   <div class="jb">
        <div class="sectionOne">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" alt="Joshua EAchus">
        </div>
        <div class="sectionTwo">
            <h2>Job Experience</h2>

            <h3>Menchies</h3>
            <p class="menchies"> Between January 2020-November 2020 I was a team member at menchies, I would mainly greet customers, help them around the store if needed and cash them out with the cash register when ready. I also am constantly busy making sure every topping and yogurt
        machine is filled up for the customers. I would usually be closing so I work 5 to 8 hour shifts every time. When closing I would put all the toppings away, clean the whole store completely and prep food for the next day.</p>

            <h3>Walgreens</h3>
            <p class="Walgreens"> I am currently working at Walgreens, which has been a great introduction into retail and has truly taught me many things. There is a diverse and large amount of tasks I do at Walgreens, one of the main tasks is running the photo department, where
      I print many kinds of photos, create canvases and many more projects. Other tasks includes stocking, outdating, cleaning duties and counting registers.</p>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ach">
        <h3>Achievements</h3>
        <div class="sectionOne">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" alt="PTK">
        </div>
        <div class="sectionTwo">
            <p>I am a member of Phi Theta Kappa. Founded on November 19, 1918 Phi Theta Kappa is the world’s largest organization specifically devoted to recognizing the achievements of honor students at 2-year institutions. Currently, PTK has approximately 3 million
                members globally.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```